# QGIS: Why does this PostGIS materialized view show up as two separate layers?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a materialized view being created by this script:

```sql
WITH intersected AS (
    SELECT source_layer.kwtid,
           source_layer.geom,
           source_layer.area,
           source_layer.alc_grade
    FROM geology_and_soil.alc_grades_gb source_layer
    WHERE st_intersects(st_transform(source_layer.geom, 27700), ( SELECT st_transform(project_boundary.geom, 27700) AS st_transform
FROM ea.project_boundary))
)
SELECT intersected.kwtid,
       intersected.alc_grade,
       CASE
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Grade 1'::text THEN 0::numeric
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Grade 2'::text THEN 0.25
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Grade 3'::text THEN 0.5
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Grade 4'::text THEN 0.75
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Grade 5'::text THEN 1::numeric
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Non Agricultural'::text THEN 0.5
           WHEN intersected.alc_grade::text = 'Urban'::text THEN 0::numeric
           ELSE NULL::numeric
       END AS score,
       intersected.geom
FROM intersected
UNION ALL
SELECT max(intersected.kwtid) + 1 AS kwtid,
       'not in layer'::character varying AS alc_grade,
       0.5 AS score,
       st_difference(( SELECT st_transform(project_boundary.geom, 27700) AS st_transform
FROM ea.project_boundary), st_transform(st_union(intersected.geom), 27700)) AS geom
FROM intersected;
```

When I open the schema from QGIS I see that two layers have been created, for each of the two selections that are unioned in the script above, as seen below

[image: QGIS postgis connexion screenshot]

I can't figure out why it is showing as two layers.

Comment: Run `SELECT DISTINCT GeometryType(geom) FROM <mat_view>;` - I suspect your expression (`ST_Difference`) generates `GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONS` or geometries of different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Where should I run that? as part of the view definition script?

Comment: No, just as a separate query.

Comment: Running that as a separate query gave me MULTIPOLYGON

Comment: do you end up with 2 geometry columns? also what is in the geometry columns view for that view?

Comment: I ended up with one geometry column. I think the issue was that I needed to set the CRS of source_layer.geom to 27700 as JGH suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometries from `intersected` are `source_layer.geom`, while the ones from the difference layer are derived from `st_transform(project_boundary.geom, 27700)`. It creates a mix of geometry CRS, and they can't be displayed together in QGIS.

Some operation creates CRS-less geometries (CRS 0) so you may have to also explicitly set the resulting CRS.

On a side note, when creating a view/materialized view, it helps to explicitly specify the geometry type/crs:

`create view .. as select geom::geometry(point,4326) from ..`

Comment: I found that the geometries were the same, but the CRS were different for these two, so thank you!